# Filter all Overlapping Line Segments based on series of line segment coordinates

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

[image]

Each line segment has 2 xy coordinates given,

Input are below,

[3,4],[5,4]

[8,4],[20,4]

[10,4],[15,4]

In the above picture, **if the lines are overlapping, it can be considered as a line segment**. May I know the mathematics behind solving it which outputs the **2 non-overlapping line segments which are [3,4],[5,4]   and  [8,4],[20,4]?**

The input I gave is **just 3 line segments** that we have to filter out to **non-overlapping line segments, so this gets complicated fast with more line segments if we don't have the proper mathematics**. I am doing this because I faced this bug in my programming :).

I will appreciate any help that I can obtain :)

Comment: What happens with partial overlap?

Comment: Are the segments in the input assumed to be parallel, or even contained in one line (parallel to the $x$ axis?)?